# how to count correct and wrong answer in radio button android

Tags: android

i am a beginner  Android developer 
I use radio button group  for Quiz App i need to count correct  and wrong answer 
but it count each i checked radio button . i do not know how ?.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    /**
     * Global Variable for count Correct answer
     */
   int count_correct_answer =0;
    /**
     *    Global Variable for count worng answer
     */
    int count_wrong_answer=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}

public void rdaio_click_group1(View view) {
    RadioGroup radio=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group1);


    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();


    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_button1:
            if (checked)

            break;
        case R.id.radio_button2:
            if (checked)
                count_correct_answer++;
            radio.clearCheck();
            break;
        case R.id.radio_button3 :
            if(checked)
            break;
    }

}

public void rdaio_click_group2(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_button12:
            if (checked)
                count_correct_answer++;
                break;
        case R.id.radio_button22:
            if (checked)

            break;
        case R.id.radio_button32 :
            if(checked)
                break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried my answer ?

Comment: i tried is the same wrong with me i [ my problem is when i press on radio button  many times  the variable  count_correct_answer  is  increased automatic i need  if i press on it many  time   increase by one only  ]

Comment: Because in your code, you have increased count_correct_answer on every selection of correct radioButton. You have to have a submit button or something to get what user selects finally.

Comment: how i make this

Comment: this my facebook need to connect with you

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/thefreedom191

Comment: Post your full activity and layout code here please.

Comment: i make as you said i make submit  button and count correct and wrong is fine  but another problem occure when i  press to button it is ok  to display count of correct and wrong answer  but when i press many time i calculate and sum previous count

Comment: i will post code

Comment: i post my a ctivity ..  check it  and really thank you for every thing you reply

Comment: i need  to reset radio button after i press submit button  as i show you to prevent calculate count correct and wrong

Answer (score 0):

Create a Button to valide(wrong or correct answer) your answer and control next question.

This button need call onClickListener.

Comment: but rdaio_click_group1 is satisfy ?

Answer (score 0):

Declare globally:

```
RadioGroup radio;
```

In onCreate:

```
radio = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group1);
```

In onClick or any Action Event:

```
radioButtonID = radio.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
View radioButton = radio.findViewById(radioButtonID);
if(radioButton.getId() == R.id.radio_button12){
   count_correct_answer++;
}
else{
   count_wrong_answer++;
}
```

As far as I understood, You want to reset radioButton selection. So, I added these codes to reset radioGroups and count_correct_answer, count_wrong_answer:

Add below codes after showing Success/Failed toast in `submit_answer(View view)`:

```
radio_groub1_button.clearCheck();
radio_groub2_button.clearCheck();
.
.
.
radio_groub8_button.clearCheck();

count_correct_answer = 0;
count_wrong_answer = 0;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but give me error  
can i ask if i write this code in correct way or not ?

Comment: my code consist of more multi group button  i implement them in on method  submit answer are this right .

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be alright. Isn't it working properly?

Comment: really need help i am very  confuse.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one problem in the code that you provided.

First of all, start by checking the spellings that you have used for the `onClick` method in xml. You have defined `public void *rdaio_click_group<number>*`, it's *radio*, just ensure that you have it spelled the same way in both xml and java.

Secondly, you should always initialize view and stuff within the `onCreate` method or the `onCreateView` method for fragments. So, declare `RadioGroup radioGroup;` outside onCreate to make it a global variable and then within the onCreate, type

`radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group1);`

In your `switch` part, you are confusing yourself and the app as to what you want to do. In

```
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_button1:
            if (checked)


            break;
     ......
     }
```

At this point, the app knows that if the `view.getId()` evaluates to true, then, it is supposed try the `if` condition, then, only when the boolean `checked` evaluates to true, the switch statement is supposed to break.

When you do not have a parentheses (the `{}` brackets) after *if*, *switch* conditions and loops, then the compiler will assume that all the code upto the next ';' (semi-colon) is what you want to include in the parentheses and nothing else. Now, you have left a blank line after the `if` condition probably to say that you want nothing to happen when this condition is true, the compiler doesn't know this. Thus, by default, it includes the `break` statement in the `if` condition, this happens because the next semi-colon after the `if` condition is includes the `break` statement.

Android studio doesn't allow this, if you want to do nothing with the if condition, then don't use it or place empty parentheses after it so that Android Studio knows that you want to do nothing when the condition is true, you must always have a break statement for every `case`, whereas you have the break statement only for those instances when the condition evaluates to true, what is the app supposed to do when the condition is false?

It will simply keep trying the next case, until it reaches the `default` one, now if any one of the previously tried cases evaluates to `true` and has a reachable `break` statement, then the app will perform all the tasks that were required to be performed for both the cases (the original one and the new one). Otherwise the app will simply implement the `default` case and produce a wrong output.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
 * declare object variable for each groupe button
 */
RadioGroup  radio_groub1_button,radio_groub2_button, radio_groub3_button   , radio_groub4_button;
RadioGroup  radio_groub5_button , radio_groub6_button ,radio_groub7_button , radio_groub8_button ;

/**
 * Global Variable for count Correct answer
 */
```

int count_correct_answer =0;
    /**
     *    Global Variable for count worng answer
     */
    int count_wrong_answer=0;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    /**
     * find ID for group button 1 to group button 8
     */
    radio_groub1_button = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio_group1) ;
    radio_groub2_button = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio_group2) ;
    radio_groub3_button = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio_group3) ;
    radio_groub4_button = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio_group4) ;
    radio_groub5_button = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio_group5) ;
    radio_groub6_button = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio_group6) ;
    radio_groub7_button = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio_group7) ;
    radio_groub8_button = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio_group8) ;

}

public void submit_answer(View view){
    int selectteed1 = radio_groub1_button.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton radio_button1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectteed1);
    String button1= radio_button1.getText().toString();
    /**
     * get id of correct answer and store in variable.
     */
    int  button_g1= R.id.radio_button2;

    if(selectteed1 == button_g1)  {
       // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Yes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        count_correct_answer++;
    }     else {count_wrong_answer++;}

    /**
     * cheked radio button  that  selectted in group1 and get id .
     * */
   int selectteed2 = radio_groub2_button.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton radio_button2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectteed2);
    String button2 =radio_button2.getText().toString();
    /**
     * get id of correct answer and store in variable.
     */
    int  button_g2= R.id.radio_button12;
    /**
     * check  for correct answer , wrong  and count it .
     */
    if(selectteed2== button_g2)  {

        count_correct_answer++;
    }
    else {count_wrong_answer++;}

    int selectteed3 = radio_groub3_button.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton radio_button3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectteed3);
    String button3 = radio_button3.getText().toString();
    /**
     * get id of correct answer and store in variable.
     */
    int  button_g3= R.id.radio_button33;
    /**
     * check  for correct answer , wrong  and count it .
     */
    if(selectteed3== button_g3)  {

        count_correct_answer++;
    } else {count_wrong_answer++;}

    /**
     * cheked radio button  that  selectted in group1 and get id .
     */
    int selectteed4 = radio_groub4_button.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton radio_button4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectteed4);
    /**
     * get id of correct answer and store in variable.
     */
    int  button_g4= R.id.radio_button14;
    /**
     * check  for correct answer , wrong  and count it .
     */
    if(selectteed4== button_g4)  {

        count_correct_answer++;
    }
    else {count_wrong_answer++;}

    /**
     * cheked radio button  that  selectted in group1 and get id .
     */
    int selectteed5 = radio_groub5_button.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton radio_button5 = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectteed5);
    /**
     * get id of correct answer and store in variable.
     */
    int  button_g5= R.id.radio_button25;
    /**
     * check  for correct answer , wrong  and count it .
     */
    if(selectteed5== button_g5)  {

        count_correct_answer++;
    }
    else {count_wrong_answer++;}

    /**
     * cheked radio button  that  selectted in group1 and get id .
     */
    int selectteed6 = radio_groub6_button.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton radio_button6 = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectteed6);
    /**
     * get id of correct answer and store in variable.
     */
    int  button_g6= R.id.radio_button26;
    /**
     * check  for correct answer , wrong  and count it .
     */
    if(selectteed6== button_g6)  {

        count_correct_answer++;
    }
    else {count_wrong_answer++;}

    /**
     * cheked radio button  that  selectted in group1 and get id .
     */
    int selectteed7 = radio_groub7_button.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton radio_button7 = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectteed7);
    /**
     * get id of correct answer and store in variable.
     */
    int  button_g7= R.id.radio_button27;
    /**
     * check  for correct answer , wrong  and count it .
     */
    if(selectteed7== button_g7)  {

        count_correct_answer++;
    }
    else {count_wrong_answer++;}
   /**
    * cheked radio button  that  selectted in group1 and get id .
    */
    int selectteed8 = radio_groub8_button.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton radio_button8 = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectteed8);
    /**
     * get id of correct answer and store in variable.
     */
    int  button_g8= R.id.radio_button28;
    /**
     * check  for correct answer , wrong  and count it .
     */
    if(selectteed8== button_g8)  {

        count_correct_answer++;
    }
    else {count_wrong_answer++;}

    String succeed  = "Number of correct answer is \t "+ count_correct_answer + "\n you are done";
    String faild = "Number of wrong answer is \t "+ count_wrong_answer + "\n you are faild";
        if(count_correct_answer >= count_wrong_answer){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),succeed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
   else{Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),faild, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}






}
```

XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Q_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="@string/Q1" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="@string/button3" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Q_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="@string/Q2" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button12" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button22" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button32"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button32" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Q_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="@string/Q3" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button13" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button23" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button33"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button33" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Q_4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="@string/Q4" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button14" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button24"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button24" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button34"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button34" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Q_5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="@string/Q5" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button15" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button25"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button25" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button35"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button35" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Q_6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="@string/Q6" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button16" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button26"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button26" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button36"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button36" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Q_7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="@string/Q7" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button17" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button27"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button27" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button37"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button37" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Q_8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="@string/Q8" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button18" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button28"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button28" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button38"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button38" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="submit_answer"
        android:text="@string/submit"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/show_answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:padding="23dp"
        android:text="" />`enter code here`
```

Comment: From where are you calling  submit_answer(View view) method ? Can't find it

Comment: what did you mean this  from where ? it call when i press on button submit answer! if some thing wrong please explain to me.

Comment: Sorry, I missed it. Try out my updated answer please. I've added code to reset radio buttons and score on button click.